# CoffeeScript Style Guide

Tags: coffeescript

I've been trying to apply PEP8 as closely as possible to CoffeeScript.

Are there any other coding conventions you follow?

Comment: Hmm, maybe a question this open-ended belongs at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 10):

I use the postfix form of if/unless only for guard constructs:

```
return   if not valid
break    if finished
continue if not important
```

Not for assignments:

```
mood = greatlyImproved if singing
```

My reasoning is based on the condition being hidden off to the right and a control flow path being on one indentation level.

When I look at a block of code, I can scan down the left and can see the control flow. Code which follows a return is obviously only reachable if the return only happens sometimes, so it stands out. It's a recognizable pattern and having it in one line is better than two.

An assignment doesn't stand out however and it's easier to overlook the condition on the right. If an assignment only happens sometimes, I think an if with indentation is clearer:

```
if singing
    mood = greatlyImproved
```